# Warnign in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I can't get my data from database , I keep getting the same error

> Notice: Undefined variable: articles in :\xampp\htdocs\SalesManagementProject\Views\articles.php on line 25
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in :\xampp\htdocs\SalesManagementProject\Views\articles.php on line 25

my loop

```
 <?php
 foreach($articles as $art)
 {
  echo '<tr>
         <td>'.$art['Id'].'</td>
         <td>'.$art['ref'].'</td>
         <td>'.$art['desig'].'</td>
        </tr>';
 }
 ?>
```

Model

```
 <?php
class ArticlesModel
{
    public function getArticles()
    {
        $pdo=new PDO_connect();
        $q= $pdo->PDO()->query('SELECT * FROM articles');
        return $q->fetchAll();
    }
}
?>
```

Controller

```
<?php
class ArticlesControllers
{
    public function loadArticles()
    {
        include (dirname(__FILE__).'/../Models/ArticlesModel.php');
        $art_table = new ArticlesModel();
        $articles = $art_table->getArticles();
        include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../Views/articles.php');
    }
}
?>
```

index

```
<?php
   session_start();
  include ('PDO_connect.php');
   $p='home';

  if (isset($_GET['p']))
  {
       $p=$_GET['p'];
   }
   include('Controllers/ArticlesControllers.php');
$arts=new ArticlesControllers();
$arts->loadArticles();
?>
```

So what i must do?

Comment: where is `$articles` defined? find that first

Comment: which one is your line 25 clarify

Comment: line 25 the foreach line Mirza Obaid

Comment: articles  my table in database

Answer (score -1):

Simple, in your controller section after the `public function loadArticles() {` add

```
global $articles;
```

Because $articles is assigned inside of a function, you need to global it to read it in another area.  
BTW you should define `$articles` as an array in index.php to make it properly defined

```
 $articles = array();
```

BTW passing a named variable in / out of a class is not very proper programming, but I wanted you to have a quick solution.

A better solution is to have the public function `return ($articles)` and  in your index.php `$articles = $arts->loadArticles();`

Comment: Thank you 
I did that but its still now work ok there is no Warning now but does not bring anything from database :(

Comment: Well that's a different matter you will have to use `print_r` in various places